# How do I instantiate a list of objects, where each object has 3 data types?

Tags: apex, json, data, constructor

JS developer here. I'm sending a JSON node to my Apex class and it's in the following format:

```
"myNodeName" : [
   {
      "id": "a123",
      "foo": true,
      "bar": [listOfThings]
   },
   {
      "id": "b456",
      "foo": true,
      "bar": [listOfThings]
   }
]
```

What is the proper constructor syntax for something like this? Here's what I'm trying:

`Map<String, Object> myData = (Map<String, Object>)(attachmentJSON.get(key));`

Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at [JSON2Apex](https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<Object> myData = (List<Object>)(attachmentJSON.get(key));
```

works in my case.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! What data type is `attachmentJSON` ? I realise you've solved your own problem here but it'd be great to have a bit more info to help others in the future.

Comment: @MattLacey, sorry for the late reply. My attachmentJSON is type: Map<String, Object>

Answer (score -2):

Using a generic Object identifier should work. Once in Apex, it will need to be explicitly typecast to an object to be processed further and have any DML operation.

If you are sending the Salesforce recordIds, then you can get the sObjectType of the record Id and cast your Object instance to the corresponding sObject instance.

```
Schema.SObjectType objectApiName = ((Id)recordId).getsobjecttype();
```

If not, then you need to include some identifier to know which object the particular instance needs to be cast to.